# What's the difference between 大臣 and 閣僚?

Tags: word-choice, words

I understand 大臣 means "minister" and 閣僚 means "cabinet minister", but I am curious what's the difference between these two terms ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both mean the same thing. The difference is how they combine with other words.

According to [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/7435/meaning/m1u/%E5%A4%A7%E8%87%A3/), 大臣 is more about individuals while 閣僚 is more about the ministers as a group of people.

My impression is that they are not so interchangeable.

- 外務大臣 *Minister of Foreign Affairs*. Not 外務閣僚
- 末は博士か大臣か *will become a PhD or a minister in future* - an oldish set phrase to describe a promising child (although I don't see much future for Japanese PhD's and ministers now). 閣僚 is not possible.
- 首相は関係閣僚に対応を指示した *Prime minister told ministers in charge to take necessary actions*. 大臣 is not possible.
- 閣僚経験者 *A person who was a minister in the past*. To me 大臣経験者 sounds OK, but it is much less common.

Answer (score -3):

大臣 may be best translated as "chancellor". My impression is this term has been deprecated in modern government and is not used anymore.

Comment: ちなみに日本の「総理大臣」は岸田文雄です